# Training brain.js multiple times?

Tags: javascript, node.js, brain.js

How can I train new information(Only the new information,not everything again, since it would cost too much performance) to my neural network made with brain.js after the first training?

Comment: I assume you would save the net with `toJSON`, and then load with `fromJSON`, and then call `train` after loading.    ps.  Not used brain.js, but I assume this should do it.

Comment: Tried that, but doesn't seem to work. the neural network loses previous information with that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its a little rough but you could achieve that using this structure:

if we join 2 training data sets, old with new one and then retrain with `keepNetworkIntact: true` then our NN will be retrained much much faster than as if we retrain it from scratch.

```
let net = new brain.NeuralNetwork();

// pre-training
net.train([
    {input: [0, 0], output: [0]},
    {input: [1, 1], output: [0]}
 ]);

// resume training with new data set
net.train([
        {input: [0, 0], output: [0]},  // old training data set
        {input: [1, 1], output: [0]}
    ].concat([
        {input: [0, 1], output: [1]},  // joining new training data set
        {input: [1, 0], output: [1]},
    ],
    {keepNetworkIntact:true}
);
```

i know Brain.JS was about to introduce a feature called `resumeableTraining` which i am not sure if implemented. Its worth checking docs though.

Happy Braining!!!

Comment: This solves the case, but I've notice something: If I use the browser version, installing gpu.js doesn't speed up the trainning. Why?

Comment: Brain.js is dependent on gpu.js internally. Are you telling you are trying gpu.js without without node just on browser and brain.js training is not fast enough?

Comment: If my solution helped, appreciate if you could accept that as an asnwer. Thanks

Comment: Yes, both with and without gpu.js the performance is the same: takes around 3~5 seconds to train a small amount of information, with 250 iterations.

Comment: Please note that Brain.JS already internally uses gpu.js. If you choose to stitch them together otherwise, you might need to explore BrainJS codebase to get a better hand of how it's internally wired so you can custom implement to your own specs.

Comment: Does the node.js version of brain.js use GPU as well?

Comment: yes it does - https://towardsdatascience.com/gpu-accelerated-neural-networks-in-javascript-195d6f8e69ef

Comment: [This way is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52798804/resuming-training-on-a-brain-js-neural-network-model), use fromJson instead

Comment: The `keepNetworkIntact` has been renamed to `reinforce`.